# Woocommerce products shortcode - Divi theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

In a woocommerce installation with Divi theme installed I am using products shortcode: `[products limit="-1" columns="3" per_page="12" paginate="true"]` . In `functions.php` I am trying to filter the products displaying by using `woocommerce_product_query` but it is not working. I am still getting all the products

```
function my_pre_get_posts_query2( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post__in', [245609, 245610]);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_pre_get_posts_query2', 9999, 1 );
```

Comment: You need to add attribute in product shortcode like,
[products limit="-1" columns="3" per_page="12" paginate="true" ids="245609, 245610"]
For this you can visit, https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: @YagnikSangani ok but how I can do it dynamic? For example each user that is logged in must see specific products. How I can edit this shortcode?

Comment: There are two ways to do that but it depends on you how you want to use that like one as above shortcode by adding attribute "ids" and the second way by using filter hook "woocommerce_shortcode_products_query" where you can do some condition which you want to add. You can find that filter here, https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: I have answered it in detail with the example, you can see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two ways:

**1. By adding attribute "ids" in the product listing shortcode**

```
[products limit="-1" columns="3" per_page="12" paginate="true" ids="245609, 245610"]
```

**2. By filter hook for product shortcode to add the attribute ids**

Something like below,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_by_specific_ids' );

function woocommerce_shortcode_products_by_specific_ids( $args ) {
    $args['ids'] = array(245609, 245610);
    // if above line not working then try with below line
    // $args['ids'] = "245609, 245610";
    return $args;
}
```